# Programmatic testing of API proxies

Tags: java, testing, apigee

I was evaluating the APIGEE proxy apis and accessing by programmatic deploy and invoke.
I downloaded the sample programs (api-pltform-samples-master). While testing the simpleProxy, I ran the deploy.sh and kept receiving the error:

---

```
Deploying to test on https://api.enterprise.apigee.com using batabya and batabya
Writing ../simpleProxy/deploy.sh to ./deploy.sh
Writing ../simpleProxy/invoke.sh to ./invoke.sh
Writing ../simpleProxy/apiproxy/weatherapi.xml to apiproxy/weatherapi.xml
Writing ../simpleProxy/apiproxy/proxies/default.xml to apiproxy/proxies/default.xml
Writing ../simpleProxy/apiproxy/resources/jsc/changeResponse.js to apiproxy/resources/jsc/changeResponse.js
Writing ../simpleProxy/apiproxy/resources/jsc/generateResponse.js to apiproxy/resources/jsc/generateResponse.js
Writing ../simpleProxy/apiproxy/resources/jsc/MashItUp.js to apiproxy/resources/jsc/MashItUp.js
Writing ../simpleProxy/apiproxy/resources/py/calculateAddress.py to apiproxy/resources/py/calculateAddress.py
Writing ../simpleProxy/apiproxy/resources/py/setHeader.py to apiproxy/resources/py/setHeader.py
Writing ../simpleProxy/apiproxy/resources/py/Timer.py to apiproxy/resources/py/Timer.py
Writing ../simpleProxy/apiproxy/resources/xsl/rewriteEndpoint.xsl to apiproxy/resources/xsl/rewriteEndpoint.xsl
Writing ../simpleProxy/apiproxy/targets/default.xml to apiproxy/targets/default.xml
```

Import failed to /v1/organizations/batabya/apis?action=import&name=weatherapi with status 401:

If 'State: deployed', then your API Proxy is ready to be invoked.
Run '$ sh invoke.sh'
If you get errors, make sure you have set the proper account settings in /setup/setenv.sh

---

FYI: I have created my profile with admin rights.

Answer (score 2):

The 401 error indicates an issue with authentication.  There are 3 factors that comprise authentication here: (1) organization name, (2) username and (3) password.

The (1) organization name and (2) are username are configured in setenv.sh.  The (3) password is prompted for from deploy.sh.

Make sure you have set your org and username by modifying the following two lines in  setenv.sh :

```
org="Enter the name of your organization here"
username="Enter your Apigee username"
```

Comment: Thanks Randy. I was providing the details but the alias for username did not work - whereas e-mail ID worked.

Answer (score 1):

One important clarification:

username="Enter your Apigee username"

This value needs to be the *email address* associated with your account on enterprise.apigee.com.

We'll update the README to clarify this.

Comment: Hi Andrew,Thanks much. The email id worked (strangely the alias doesn't). Now I face (Deploy failed with status 500) - "message" : "com/apigee/CityLookup : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0" - which I guess is because of jdk version mismatch between code-compiled with runtime.  Any thoughts.